# Is there a way in luxon to deal with impossible or "dual times" caused by DST

Tags: luxon

So to set the scene we have a requirement that every night at 01:30 UK time now this is fine for most days of the year but if I create use

```
DateTime.fromObject({year:2022, month:3, day:27, hour: 1, minute: 30, second: 0 }, { zone: 'Europe/London' });
```

What I get back is 2022-03-27T02:30:00.000+01:00 not 2022-03-27T01:00:00.000+01:00 or 2022-03-27T02:00:00.000+01:00 is there any way for me to force this functionality within luxon or another more suitable library that can handle this?

```
function dateTimeDisambiguation(timezone,plaindate) {

  tz = new Temporal.TimeZone(timezone);
  const instants = tz.getPossibleInstantsFor(plaindate);
  
  switch(instants.length){
    case 0:
      const transition = tz.getPreviousTransition(tz.getInstantFor(plaindate, { disambiguation: 'later'}));
      const beforeTransition = transition.subtract({ nanoseconds: 1 });
      return beforeTransition;
    default:
        return instants[0];
  }
}

tz = new Temporal.TimeZone('Europe/London');

skipSimple = {year: 2022, month: 3, day: 27, hour: 1, minute: 30 };
doubleSimple = {year: 2022, month: 10, day: 30, hour: 1, minute: 30 };
normalSimple = {year: 2022, month: 10, day: 30, hour: 10, minute: 30 };

const skip = dateTimeDisambiguation('Europe/London', skipSimple);
const double = dateTimeDisambiguation('Europe/London', doubleSimple);
const normal = dateTimeDisambiguation('Europe/London', normalSimple);

console.log(skip.toString()); => // "2022-03-27T00:59:59.999999999Z"
console.log(double.toString()); => // "2022-10-30T00:30:00Z"
console.log(normal.toString()); => // "2022-10-30T10:30:00Z"
```

Comment: 1:30am does not exist on that day in that timezone. When you ask 'that can handle this', you should explain in what way you want to handle it, because currently it's handing it by skipping forward which is a reasonable choice.

Comment: we don't want it to skip forward we need it in this case to return 2022-03-27T01:00:00.000+01:00 as stated as this time is still before 1:30 london time rather than 2:00 which is after.

Comment: I know Temporal will deal with this but this has yet to be released. https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/ambiguity.html

Comment: I see, could you use the UTC time (doesn't have daylight savings) and convert? Or will it still skip ahead?

Comment: Actually does 1PM really exist? Or should the clock switch to 2pm after 0:59:59 ?

Comment: 0:59:59.999999999999 is also acceptable the main requirement is when is the last possible moment that is before 01:30 or when is the last possible moment as one could argue that 02:00 is all times from 01:00 - 02:00.

Comment: Given that luxon supports microseconds, I'm certain `0:59:59.999` should be representable.

Comment: the main issue is luxon doesn't seem to have a "transition time"

Comment: Explain transition time?

Comment: the issue is that not all DST time jumps are one hour or happen on the hour so knowing when the jump was is mightily important.

Comment: I'm strongly feeling this is an 'XY' problem, and there's a super reasonable way to fix this. Perhaps you should take a step back? Why are you using local time?

Comment: Because we have to perform a task every day before 01:30 AM (local time but not the users time) otherwise bad things happen. I know why not make a system that doesn't have bad things happen if stuff isn't done before 01:30 AM but I have no control over this. luxon returning 2:30 doesn't help as we use this to order the jobs in soonest needs to be done order so we can prioritise the jobs that are about to run out but if this shows as having an hour extra than we do it can cause misses.

Comment: Ok, silly idea... could you just write an if statement which is in pseudo code: `if (time > 1:30am) time -= 31 minutes`, that should give you a timestamp like `0:59am`

Comment: this works for most cases but it also assumes that all DST changes happen on the hour and move the time by 1 hour.

Comment: Then keep running a statement like this in a loop until you find an appropriate moment. The smallest timezone offset is 15 minutes.